# How can I reverse the digits in an unsigned long?

Tags: c, long-integer, unsigned

I want to reverse a number but it's an `unsigned long`. I'm not familiar with the qualities of `unsigned long`, however.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long num, reversed = 0;
    scanf_s("%lu", &num);

    while(num > 0)
    {
        reversed *= 10;
        reversed = reversed + num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }

    printf("%lu", reversed);
    return 0;
}
```

If, for example, the input is `888888888889`, the output is different.

And I think it's because it does proximity, if that's the right word.

I'm not sure about `%lu` either.

How can I reverse the digits of an `unsigned long`?

Comment: Don't use `scanf_s`. It's not portable and has too many opportunities to be used incorrectly. Disable the warning if it bothers you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `unsigned long` might not be big enough to hold the number `888888888889`. Check the value of `LONG_MAX` from `<limits.h>`. To ensure you can hold that number, you need to ensure you use a 64-bit integer. `long long` is defined to be at least 64 bits big. You should then also use `%llu` instead of `%lu` in calls to `scanf()` and `printf()`. See this [list of C data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types).

Comment: Ah, smart. I wouldn't have thought of this without testing on a platform where `888888888889` can't fit in an `unsigned long`.

Comment: @JL2210: Windows has 32-bit `long`s even in 64-bit mode, contrary to what all other operating systems do.

Comment: `long` as 32 or 64 bit is a compiler implementation detail, not an OS one.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: while it is the compiler that implements it, the operating system vendors and CPU makers usually recommend the data model that should be used, similar to calling conventions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models; it's mostly the platform that determines how long an, uhm, `long` is , not the brand of compiler you use.

Comment: @G.Sliepen s/recommend/demand/. To use any library functions or system calls you have to use the correct `long`. I learned that when trying to modify GCC to put 64-bit `long` on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

As @G.Sliepen notes in their answer, this is caused because `888888888889` can't fit in an `unsigned long`. To fix this, use `unsigned long long`, which is guaranteed to hold at least 64 bits of data:

```
    unsigned long long num, reversed = 0; // unsigned long long
    scanf_s("%llu", &num); // %llu
    // ...
    printf("%llu", reversed); // %llu
```

Perhaps you also need to print a newline to see the output:

```
printf("%llu\n", reversed);
```

Answer (score -2):

Here you have version reversing the number in any base (the display function actually displays only up to base 16 but you can easily amend it adding more digits)

```
unsigned long long reverse(unsigned long long val, unsigned base)
{
    unsigned long long result = 0;
    while(val)
    {
        result *= base;
        result += val % base;
        val /= base;
    }
    return result;
}

char *strreverse(char *str);
char *llutoa(char *num, unsigned long long val, unsigned base);

int main()
{
    unsigned long long number = 6786785648796575;
    char s1[65], s2[65];

    for(unsigned base = 2; base <= 16; base++)
    {
        printf("Base %02u Number = %s Reveresed = %s\n", 
        base, llutoa(s1, number, base), llutoa(s2, reverse(number, base), base));
    }
}

char *strreverse(char *str)
{
    char *end = str, *saved = str;
    while(*end) end++; end--;

    while(end > str) 
    {
        int ch = *end;

        *end-- = *str;
        *str++ = ch;
    }
    return saved;
}

const char * const digits = "01234567890ABCDEF";

char *llutoa(char *num, unsigned long long val, unsigned base)
{
    size_t pos = 0;

    while(val)
    {
        num[pos++] = digits[val % base];
        val /= base;
    }
    num[pos] = 0;

    return strreverse(num);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/MQ7jjV